# Python: paramiko SCPException connection timeout error

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, scp

From one Windows server i have a python script that connects to a remote Linux host and transfers some data via SSH/SCP. The script is scheduled to execute every morning via the WindowsTaskScheduler of the local server.

The problem i have is that sometimes (not Always strangely enough, and the last days this happens more often) the execution never completes as i get a connection timeout error. From the log of the script:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 665, in recv out = self.in_buffer.read(nbytes, self.timeout)
  File "D:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\buffered_pipe.py", line160, in read raise PipeTimeout() paramiko.buffered_pipe.PipeTimeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scp.py", line 314, in _recv_confirm
    msg = self.channel.recv(512)
  File "D:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 667, in recv
    raise socket.timeout()socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 235, in <module>
    copy_file_to_remote(LOCAL_FOLDER, file_path, DESTINATION_FOLDER, ssh)
  File "script.py", line 184, in copy_file_to_remote
    scp.put(win_path, linux_path)
  File "D:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scp.py", line 154, in put
    self._send_files(files)
  File "D:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scp.py", line 255, in _send_files
    self._recv_confirm()
  File "D:\App\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scp.py", line 316, in _recv_confirm
        raise SCPException('Timout waiting for scp response')
    scp.SCPException: Timout waiting for scp response*
```

My question is if it is possible to maximize the connection timeout limit in the ssh/scp funtions used in the script or in general how can i make my script to reestablish the connection, keep it open with keepalives or something similar.

It would be also nice if there is way to know at which side of the connection the problem exists, local server or remote machine. This could help a lot for troubleshooting. Any ideas/help very much appreciated!